# Condom poster: What should 爪 in ...因爪安全性行为感染艾滋病 actually be? And why is 经 in 预防艾滋病经性传播?

Tags: translation, transcription

**Question**:  What should 爪 in 天津市平均每周都有１名学生因**爪**安全性行为感染艾滋病 actually be?  And why is 经 in 预防艾滋病**经**性传播?

Why I ask: this poster has appeared in some campus bathrooms (in the women's ones, at least):

> [image: message and anthropomorphic condom]
> <sup>([large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah5Vs.jpg))</sup>

Zooming in, the first part is:

> [image: zoomed in Chinese text]

I transcribe and translate this to:

> 天津市每发现１０例ＨＩＶ感染者
> 其中就有７例是通过男男同性性行为传播
> 天津市平均每周都有１名学生因**爪**安全性行为感染艾滋病
>
> In Tianjin, in every 10 cases of discovered HIV infection
> among these are 7 cases spread through male-male same-sex sexual activity
> The Tianjin average, every week has 1 student, because of [爪 (?)] unsafe sex, is infected with aids

I don't think [爪](http://dict.cn/%E7%88%AA) (=claw) is correct, but I couldn't find the correct character.  (My phone suggests , but it doesn't appear in dictionaries.)

And I transcribe and translate what the condom says:

> [image]
>
> 预防艾滋病**经**性传播
> 从坚持正确使用安全套开始
>
> To prevent aids [经 (?)] and sexually transmitted diseases
> start with insisting on proper use of condoms

I'm not sure what 经 ([YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BB%8F), [dict.cn](http://dict.cn/%E7%BB%8F)) is doing here.  I don't see a relevant definition.  Is it yet another word for "and"?  Or maybe it means "and other", or "along with".

Comment: It is 不安全性行为 (unsafe sex) , not 爪安全性行为, please edit your question

Comment: Ah, of course!  (Now I feel a bit silly.)  I think it's okay; that can be included in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **不**安全性行为 (unsafe sex) , not 爪安全性行为

经 means 'through'

性 means 'sex'

预防艾滋病(经)性传播 = prevent aids spread (through) sex

A more clear phrasing might help new learners understand better - 预防艾滋病经(由)性(愛/交)传播

经由 = 'through'

性愛 = 'love making'

性交 = 'sexual intercourse'